# why can't i write this camel route?

Tags: apache-camel

```
from("e1")
  .split()
     .method("bean", "m1")
     .to("e2")
  .end()
  .split()
     .method("bean", "m2")
     .to("e3");
```

The compiler complains about the 2nd `to`. The reason is that for some reason, it thinks the second `split` returns `ExpressionCaluse` rather than `ExpressionClause<SplitDefinition>`, which causes the following `method` return type to be `Object` rather than `SplitDefinition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in Eclipse, and first I got the same result as you (with the eclipse code completion showing an error). Then I rewrote the route (e.g. splitting it up with assignments to

```
ProcessorDefinition pd = from("e1").... 
pd.split()...
```

Then, back to the original code, so finally Eclipse got the idea correct and the error marker disappeared. I don't know if you was trying eclipse too?

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("e1")
              .split()
                 .method("bean", "m1")
                 .to("e2")
              .end()
              .split().method("bean", "m2")
                 .to("e3");
        }
```

I mean, it should work. The signature of split() in ProcessorDefinition is correct:

```
public ExpressionClause<SplitDefinition> split()
```

I guess this is a glitch somewhere in my dev. env. and probably yours too..  or something. Odd, anyway.

Comment: Which Camel version are you using? I double checked source for camel 2.9.2 and 2.10.0 and both defined ExpressionClause<SplitDefinition> as return type for split() method in ProcessorDefinition.